# The symbol used in the evaluation of an integral

Tags: calculus, notation

What is the standard symbol used in the evaluation of an integral? $\int_a^b f(x) \,\mathrm dx =F(x)^b_a$.  I am refering to the symbol(s) that stands for $F(b)-F(a)$, sometimes like a vertical bar and sometimes two brackets

Comment: What do you mean? As you say, some people use a vertical bar and others use square brackets...

Comment: Both the vertical bar and the square brackets are *standard* symbols for this. Use whatever you like.